# moomasonry not compatible with new versions of mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I want to use http://mootools.net/forge/p/moomasonry in a project I am working on but the plugin is not compatible with mootools 1.4.5 (the latest release). I am quite confused as to what I need to do to make it work. I don't mind altering the code if someone gives me a pointer.

The error is:

name.toLowerCase is not a function

var getter = propertyGetters[name.toLowerCase()];

mootoo...mpat.js (line 3684)

Comment: It's ok - found an update on GitHub: https://github.com/orefalo/mooMasonry/blob/master/Source/mooMasonry.js

Comment: Anyway, have a look [**here**](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/wiki/Update-from-1.2-to-1.3) and [**here**](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/wiki/Upgrade-from-1.2-to-1.3).